# Using enumerate in a list expression gives unexpected result

Tags: python, list

I'm playing around with list expressions. This works:

```
>> l = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
>> z = [v for i, v in enumerate(l[0:-1]) if v < l[i + 1]]
>> print(z)
[1, 3, 4]
```

But this does not:

```
>> l = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
>> z = [v for i, v in enumerate(l[1:-1]) if v < l[i + 1]] # Changed from l[0:-1] -> l[1:-1]
>> print(z)
[] # It should print [3, 4]
```

They look almost identical -- what am I missing? Removing `if v < l[i + 1]` in the second expression returns the sublist `l[1:-1]` as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate()` starts the count at `0` every time. You shortened `l` at the start by one element, but the `i` counter doesn't start at `1`, it still starts at `0`.

Pass in a start value as the second argument:

```
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(l[1:-1], 1) if v < l[i + 1]]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Wow, in hindsight this is very obvious.